# Only prints last wrong input not the correct input after validation

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

```
if grade ==2:
   var = int(input('Enter the test score: '))
   while var <0 or var > 100:
      print('Must be between 0 to 100')
      var = int(input('Enter the test score: '))
sophomore.append(var)
```

This code does validate correctly but when testing it putting invalid values three times and the fourth time correct value in prints out the last incorrect value not the correct value even thou in validated correctly.

Comment: can you make your last statement clear? It is a little hard to decipher what's the problem here.

Comment: Your code does not print any values. There are no calls to `print(var)`. Please update it.